# Compute the local mean and variance of identified pixel in image

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I want to compute the mean and standard derivation of sub region that is created by a window (dashed line) and center at identified pixel-red color( called local mean and standard derivation). This is figure to describe it
[image]

We can do it by convolution image with a mask. However, it takes long time because I only care the mean and standard derivation of a server points, while convolution  computes for whole point in image. Could you have a faster way to resolve it that only compute the mean and standard derivation at identified pixel? I am doing it by matlab. This is my code by convolution function

```
I=[18    36    70    33    64    40    62    76    71    37     5
   82    49    86    45    96    29    74     7    60    56    45
   25    32    55    48    25    30    12    82    95    77     8
   24    18    78    74    19    57    67    59    16    46    78
   28     9    59     2    29    11     7    31    75    15    25
   83    26    96     8    82    26    85    12    11    28    19
   81    64    78    70    26    33    17    72    81    16    54
   75    39    78    34    59    31    77    31    61    81    89
   89    84    29    99    79    25    26    35    65    56    76
   93    90    45     7    61    13    34    24    11    34    92
   88    82    91    81   100     4    88    70    85     8    19];
identified_position=[30 36 84 90] %indices of pixel 78, 48,72 60
mask=1/9.*ones(3,3);
mean_all=imfilter(I,mask,'same');
%Mean of identified pixels
mean_all(identified_position)
% Compute the variance
std_all=stdfilt(I,ones(3));
%std of identified pixels
std_all(identified_position)
```

This is the comparison code

```
function compare_mean(dimx,dimy)
I=randi(100,[dimx,dimy]);
rad=3;
identified_position=randi(max(I(:)),[1,5]);% Get 5 random position
function way1()

    mask=ones(rad,rad);
    mask=mask./sum(mask(:));
    mean_all=conv2(I,mask,'same');
    mean_out =mean_all(identified_position);
end
function way2()
    box_size = rad; %// Edit your window size here (an odd number is preferred)
    bxr = floor(box_size/2); %// box radius
    %// Get neighboring indices and those elements for all identified positions
    off1 = bsxfun(@plus,[-bxr:bxr]',[-bxr:bxr]*size(I,1)); %//'#neighborhood offsets
    idx = bsxfun(@plus,off1(:),identified_position); %// all absolute offsets
    I_selected_neigh = I(idx); %// all offsetted elements
    mean_out = mean(I_selected_neigh,1); %// mean output

end
way2()
time_way1=@()way1();timeit(time_way1)
time_way2=@()way2();timeit(time_way2)
end
```

Sometime the way2 has error is

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in compare_mean/way2 (line 18)
    I_selected_neigh = I(idx); %// all offsetted elements

Error in compare_mean (line 22)
way2()
```

Comment: Will you only use a 3x3 box or do you want any size ? This would lead to different approaches.

Comment: Actually, I want to any size. The 3x3 only for simple visualization

Comment: Last thing: how do you want to manage the boundaries ? Simply by averaging/stding a least number of pixels ?

Comment: Good question. I know the problem in boundary. We can add the padding points. However, The boundary points does not so affect to my method. Hence, We can ignore them. Just using option 'same' in convolution

Comment: I am intrigued as to why you would want to do this? Would you care to explain?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Yes. In the my image, I have to compute some mean value and standard derivation of a serve region. Each region indicated by center of region and they have different properties. Hence, they have different mean and standard derivation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion & Solution Codes

Given `I` as the input image, `identified_position` as the linear indices of the selected points and `bxsz` as the window/box size, the approach listed next must be pretty efficient -

```
%// Get XY coordinates
[X,Y] =  ind2sub(size(I),identified_position);
pts = [X(:) Y(:)];

%// Parameters
bxr = (bxsz-1)/2;
Isz = size(I);

%// XY coordinates of neighboring elements
[offx,offy] = ndgrid(-bxr:bxr,-bxr:bxr);
x_idx = bsxfun(@plus,offx(:),pts(:,1)');  %//'
y_idx = bsxfun(@plus,offy(:),pts(:,2)');  %//'

%// Outside image boundary elements
invalids = x_idx>Isz(1) | x_idx<1 | y_idx>Isz(2) | y_idx<1;

%// All neighboring indices
all_idx = (y_idx-1)*size(I,1) + x_idx;
all_idx(invalids) = 1;

%// All neighboring elements
all_vals = I(all_idx);
all_vals(invalids) = 0;

mean_out = mean(all_vals,1); %// final mean output

stdfilts = stdfilt(all_vals,ones(bxsz^2,1))
std_out = stdfilts(ceil(size(stdfilts,1)/2),:)  %// final stdfilt output
```

Basically, it gets all the neighbouring indices for all identified positions in one go with `bsxfun` and thus, gets all those neighbouring elements. Those selected elements are then used to get the **`mean`** and **`stdfilt`** outputs. The whole idea is to **`keep the memory requirement minimum`** and at the same time doing **`everything in a vectorized fashion`** within those selected elements. Hopefully, this must be faster!

---

### Benchmarking

**Benchmarking Code**

```
dx = 10000; %// x-dimension of input image
dy = 10000; %// y-dimension of input image
npts = 1000; %// number of points
I=randi(100,[dx,dy]); %// create input image of random intensities
identified_position=randi(max(I(:)),[1,npts]);
rad=5; %// blocksize (rad x rad)

%// Run the approaches fed with the inputs
func1 = @() way1(I,identified_position,rad); %// original approach 
time1 = timeit(func1);
clear func1

func2 = @() way2(I,identified_position,rad); %// proposed approach 
time2 = timeit(func2);
clear func2

disp(['Input size: ' num2str(dx) 'x' num2str(dy) ' & Points: ' num2str(npts)])
disp(['With Original Approach: Elapsed Time = ' num2str(time1) '(s)'])
disp(['With Proposed Approach: Elapsed Time = ' num2str(time2) '(s)'])
disp(['**Speedup w/ Proposed Approach : ' num2str(time1/time2) 'x!**'])
```

**Associated function codes**

```
%// OP's stated approach
function mean_out = way1(I,identified_position,rad)
mask=ones(rad,rad);
mask=mask./sum(mask(:));
mean_all=conv2(I,mask,'same');
mean_out =mean_all(identified_position);
return;

function mean_out = way2(I,identified_position,rad)
%//.... code from proposed approach stated earlier until mean_out %//
```

**Runtime results**

```
Input size: 10000x10000 & Points: 1000
With Original Approach: Elapsed Time = 0.46394(s)
With Proposed Approach: Elapsed Time = 0.00049403(s)
**Speedup w/ Proposed Approach : 939.0778x!**
```

Comment: Thank Divakar. I checked your solution and my solution. It is not so big different computational time. And some time it has error. I upload one code to compare your code and my code. Let look at my update question

Comment: And the line off1 = bsxfun(@plus,[-bxr:bxr]',[-bxr:bxr]*size(I,1)); . What is happen if my image size is not square for example size(I)=[110 120]

Comment: @user3051460 Those errors most likely be because some of the `identified_position` are at boundaries or close to it, so when calculating the neighboring indices, they get out of the image boundaries. In your comments you said `"The boundary points does not so affect to my method. Hence, We can ignore them. "`, so I just assumed that there won't be any such boundary or close-to-boundary elements.

Comment: @user3051460 Regarding your second query, that bsxfun code only assumes the window to be square and image size could be anything.

Comment: @user3051460 Added code showing how you can generate random positions except the ones around the boundaries which you said in your comments earlier that we can ignore those cases.

Comment: Maybe I used a wrong word to explain the points in boundary, Let see imfilter with option 'same'. It will convolution a mask with image from first pixel to last pixel. And output image has same size with original image. Hence, imfilter wit option 'same' need not add padding at pixels near boundary. That I think. So I want to applied that scheme to explain the sentence 'The boundary points does not so affect to my method. Hence, We can ignore them- that mean we don't need add padding at pixels near boundary'.

Comment: You can ignore the sentence '"The boundary points does not so affect to my method. Hence, We can ignore them. "'. Just see the way1 doing, and applied for your way. Note that way1 can do any position. Thank in advance

Comment: Thank Divakar for your answer. I can learn something from your code. It is very fast, although it does not make sense in small size of image (for example dx and dy is 128x128 and npts = 100; %// number of points